# Does this alignment of structure objects apply only to structure objects being used as elements of an array?

Tags: c, memory

In Computer Systems: a Programmer's Perspective,

> In addition, the compiler may need to add padding to the end of the
> structure so that each element in an array of structures will satisfy
> its alignment requirement. For example, consider the following
> structure declaration:
>
> ```
> struct S2 {
> int i;
> int j;
> char c;
> };
> ```
>
> If we pack this structure into 9 bytes, we can still satisfy the
> alignment requirements for ﬁelds i and j by making sure that the
> starting address of the structure satisﬁes a 4-byte alignment
> requirement.
>
> Consider, however, the following declaration:
>
> ```
> struct S2 d[4];
> ```
>
> With the 9-byte allocation, it is not possible to satisfy the
> alignment requirement for each element of d, because these elements
> will have addresses x_d, x_d + 9,x_d + 18, and x_d + 27. Instead, the
> compiler **allocates 12 bytes for structure S2, with the ﬁnal 3 bytes
> being wasted space**. That way, the elements of d will have addresses
> x_d, x_d + 12, x_d + 24, and x_d + 36. As long as x_d is a multiple of
> 4, all of the alignment restrictions will be satisﬁed.

What does "allocates 12 bytes for structure S2, with the ﬁnal 3 bytes being wasted space" happen to:

- only  S2 structure objects which are used as elements of an array, or
- any S2 structure object whether or not it is an element of an array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not only arrays but generally any place where the structure is allocated in memory. The array example was likely chosen since it's the most straightforward way to illustrate why the 3 bytes of padding is required to properly align the structure to 32-bit boundaries as required for `i`. Yet any place that allocates `s2`, including interleaved cases where `s2` is allocated on the stack along with space for other variables, should and generally will align it to 32-bit boundaries assuming `alignof(int)==4`.

As another simple example, consider this case:

```
struct s3
{
    char ch;
    struct S2 s2a;
    struct S2 s2b;
};
```

In this case, `s2a` needs to be 32-bit aligned for proper alignment of `S2` and 3 bytes of padding will usually be added between `ch` and `s2a` to properly align `s2a`, and the 3 bytes of internal padding inside `S2` (making `sizeof(S2)==12`) is needed to properly align `s2b`.

Comment: But there may be cases where padding isn't needed.  For example where an S2 struct is immediately followed in memory by three char variables.  Those normally don't need to be 32-bit aligned.

Comment: I could see some isolated cases where that wouldn't be necessary for a standalone instance, although I don't think I've ever encountered a case where the structure as a whole was ever allocated without the padding if it was allocated as a whole and wasn't packed as a whole. Although when the structure is created locally in a function and there are no stack spills, I often find the fields of the structure just moving directly into registers without the conceptual padding (although the registers might be larger than the fields).

Comment: Some of that might have to do with the existence of pointers and pointer semantics. Even if it's perfectly safe to, say, allocate a structure on the stack for a particular platform that has `sizeof(struct s2)==12` even though we only need to allocate 9 bytes in a specific case, the fact that we can create pointers to `s2` and do arithmetic on the pointers offsetting by `sizeof(s2)` will probably want to make most compilers conservative with respect to all places that allocate `s2` and allocate the full 12 bytes (along with whatever padding is required to precede it to get 32-bit alignment).